# KineticJS shape opacity

Tags: javascript, kineticjs, opacity

I need some assistance changing the opacity of a shape using KineticJS (5.0.0.).
In an mouse event, I want to change the opacity of the shape, which triggered the event. Whenever the shape is hovered, it gets visible ( opacity 1.0 ) and when it's left, it becomes invisible ( opacity 0.0 ). It works fine, whenever I redraw the whole Layer of the specified shape.

The point is, I can't redraw the whole Layer because it takes to much time ( ~300 shapes ). For that reason I changed some code, to just draw the shape.

jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/p39uH/2/  ( see lines 25 and 30 of HTML )

> var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
>           container: 'container',
>           width: 578,
>           height: 200
>         });
>         var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
>
> ```
>   var pentagon = new Kinetic.RegularPolygon({
>     x: stage.width()/2,
>     y: stage.height()/2,
>     sides: 5,
>     radius: 70,
>     fill: 'red',
>     stroke: 'black',
>     strokeWidth: 4,
>     opacity: 0.1
>   });
>
>   pentagon.on('mouseover', function() {
>     this.opacity(0.3);
>     this.draw(); // instead of layer.draw();
>   });
>
>   pentagon.on('mouseout', function() {
>     this.opacity(0.0);
>     this.draw(); // instead of layer.draw();
>   });
>   // add the shape to the layer
>   layer.add(pentagon);
>
>   // add the layer to the stage
>   stage.add(layer);
> ```

( Code is based on this: http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-set-alpha-with-kineticjs/ )

Even though I set the opacity of the shape to 0.0 when left, it's still visible as you can see. Every time it is hovered, it becomes more and more visible ( I guess the shape gets redrawn ).

Is there any way to (re)draw the shape with an opacity of 0.0 WITHOUT drawing the whole stage and/or layer ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, a quick look indicates node.draw() might be broken in 5.0.1.

Workarounds:

- Drop back to version 4.4.0
- Use layer.drawScene() which saves redraw time by not redrawing the hit-canvas.

Comment: Thanks for you replay.
I tried layer.drawScene() and in fact it works better than just using layer.draw(). Version 4.4.0 seems to work fine as you mentioned, but dropping back to that version is no option :/.

Comment: When you are using node.draw() it will drawed OVER existing picture. (without clearing existing state, because it is not possible) If you have no other elements under your node, you may use `layer.clear` method. If you have performance problems look at: https://github.com/lavrton/kineticjs-tips-and-tools#performance
Most import are layers and caching.

Comment: @lavrton, An update: Eric says node.draw has been removed. However, when node.draw was introduced in V4.4 it cleared the existing node (not overdrawn)--so, user3228838's opacity change works under 4.4.  Depending on the OP's design requirements, your suggestion of multiple layers to reduce the cost of redrawing sounds good.  Caching is great for very complex shapes. Caching is great for multiple shapes that are static and don't have to generate events. As I "read between the lines", I don't think caching would be useful here.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.


I tried your advice using multiple layers to reduce the layer.draw[Scene]() time. Works very good! 
Right now I add up to 30 rectangles to one layer instead of using one layer for about 300 rectangles. It works very fast, even on older computers. 

@markE: You seem to be very good at "reading between the lines" :D. I dont use complex shapes ( simple rectangles ) and I need to handle events on each of them. So yeah, caching doesn't seem to be useful. Anyway, as I said, multiple layers works great.

Again, thank you both for your help :)!